# Attempt to create Quickblox user returns "cancelled" in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, quickblox

Our app uses a Podfile to include 'QuickBlox', but I am unable to successfully create a new user. Here is the code, which uses an already-determined username and password. Am I missing something obvious? I cannot use the `QBRequest createSessionWithSuccessBlock` method as that is no longer in the SDK.

```
self.qbUser = [QBUUser user];
self.qbUser.login = self.user.userId;
//
// use salted SHA1 as password
//
self.qbUser.password = self.user.password;

[SVProgressHUD show];
__weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;

//
// block to start chat
//
void (^chatBlock)(QBUUser *) = ^(QBUUser *user) {
    [[QBChat instance] connectWithUser:user completion:^(NSError * _Nullable error) {
        NSLog(@"Chat Error: %@", error);
        weakSelf.isLoggedInToQb = NO;
    }];
};

//
// block for logging in an already-created user
//
void (^loginBlock)(QBUUser *) = ^(QBUUser *startUser) {
    [QBRequest logInWithUserLogin:startUser.login password:startUser.password successBlock:^(QBResponse *response, QBUUser *loggedInUser) {
        weakSelf.isLoggedInToQb = YES;
        chatBlock(startUser);
    } errorBlock:^(QBResponse *response) {
        // error handling
        NSLog(@"error: %@", response.error);
        weakSelf.isLoggedInToQb = NO;
    }];
};

//
// attempt to create the user
//
self.qbLoginRequest = [QBRequest signUp:self.qbUser successBlock:^(QBResponse * _Nonnull response, QBUUser * _Nullable user) {
    [SVProgressHUD dismiss];
    // user created, go ahead and log in
    loginBlock(user);
} errorBlock:^(QBResponse * _Nonnull response) {
    [SVProgressHUD dismiss];
    NSLog(@"Unable to create user to log in: %@", response.error.error);
    NSLog(@"request was cancelled: %@", weakSelf.qbLoginRequest.canceled ? @"YES" : @"NO");
    // I would expect a status like QBUserAlreadyExists, but..
    //if(response.status == QBResponseStatusCodeOK) {
        // try logging in anyway
        loginBlock(weakSelf.qbUser);
    //}
}];
```

The output I am getting says the request was cancelled, even though `self.qbLoginRequest.canceled` is false. Below is the console output from the code above. I suspect I am missing a step authenticating. The session was recently removed from QuickBlox, which would be the obvious first thing to check.

```
2016-05-04 10:12:50.397 charly[99771:16346643] [QBCore] Response error: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999 "cancelled" UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://api.dev.quickblox.com/session.json, NSLocalizedDescription=cancelled, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://api.dev.quickblox.com/session.json}
2016-05-04 10:12:50.397 charly[99771:16346643] [QBCore] Response error reasons: {
    error =     {
        message = cancelled;
    };
}
2016-05-04 10:12:50.398 charly[99771:16346643] [QBAuth] Create Session request error: (null)
2016-05-04 10:12:50.401 charly[99771:16346593] [QBCore] Response error: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999 "cancelled" UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://api.dev.quickblox.com/session.json, NSLocalizedDescription=cancelled, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://api.dev.quickblox.com/session.json}
2016-05-04 10:12:50.401 charly[99771:16346342] Unable to create user to log in: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999 "cancelled" UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://api.dev.quickblox.com/session.json, NSLocalizedDescription=cancelled, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://api.dev.quickblox.com/session.json}
2016-05-04 10:12:50.401 charly[99771:16346342] request was cancelled: NO
2016-05-04 10:12:50.401 charly[99771:16346593] [QBCore] Response error reasons: {
    error =     {
        message = cancelled;
    };
}
2016-05-04 10:12:50.401 charly[99771:16346593] [QBCore] Request URL:https://api.dev.quickblox.com/session.json
2016-05-04 10:12:50.401 charly[99771:16346593] [QBCore] Request method: POST
2016-05-04 10:12:50.402 charly[99771:16346593] [QBCore] Request parameters:{
    "application_id" = 39734;
    "auth_key" = c85fDePFNeGUkBh;
    nonce = 319;
    signature = d13c7681ea38fe7d3c6eff3a5fc1be251810401b;
    timestamp = 1462371170;
}
2016-05-04 10:12:50.402 charly[99771:16346593] [QBCore] Request headers: {
    "Accept-Language" = "en-US;q=1";
    "Content-Type" = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    "QB-OS" = "iOS 9.3";
    "QB-SDK" = "iOS 2.7.2";
    "QuickBlox-REST-API-Version" = "0.1.1";
    "User-Agent" = "charly/1.0 (iPhone; iOS 9.3; Scale/3.00)";
}
2016-05-04 10:12:50.470 charly[99771:16346593] [QBCore] Response error: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999 "cancelled" UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://api.dev.quickblox.com/session.json, NSLocalizedDescription=cancelled, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://api.dev.quickblox.com/session.json}
2016-05-04 10:12:50.470 charly[99771:16346593] [QBCore] Response error reasons: {
    error =     {
        message = cancelled;
    };
}
2016-05-04 10:12:50.470 charly[99771:16346593] [QBAuth] Create Session request error: (null)
2016-05-04 10:12:50.473 charly[99771:16346342] error: 
   Error reasons:{
    error =     {
        message = cancelled;
    };
}
2016-05-04 10:12:50.473 charly[99771:16346593] [QBCore] Response error: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999 "cancelled" UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://api.dev.quickblox.com/session.json, NSLocalizedDescription=cancelled, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://api.dev.quickblox.com/session.json}
2016-05-04 10:12:50.473 charly[99771:16346593] [QBCore] Response error reasons: {
    error =     {
        message = cancelled;
    };
}
2016-05-04 10:12:50.731 charly[99771:16346593] [QBCore] Answer DNS chat.quickblox.com [connectivity-1]
```

I did try adding a session, but that caused the code to crash.

```
QBASession *session = [QBASession new];
[[QBSession currentSession] startSessionWithDetails:session];
```

If I put that above the creation of the `QBUUser`, the code crashed at the line calling `QBRequest signUp`.

Comment: Please create issue on [github](https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-ios-sdk) and attach full logs.
For enabling full logs: // Enables Quickblox REST API calls debug console output [QBSettings setLogLevel:QBLogLevelDebug]; // Enables detailed XMPP logging in console output [QBSettings enableXMPPLogging]; Your help is highly appreciated and will help us to improve our ability to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had initialized my QuickBlox settings as:

```
[QBSettings setApplicationID:kApplicationID];
[QBSettings setAuthKey:kAuthKey];
[QBSettings setAuthSecret:kAuthSecret];
[QBSettings setAccountKey:kAccountKey];
[QBSettings setAutoReconnectEnabled:YES];
[QBSettings setChatDNSLookupCacheEnabled:YES];
// for development
QBSettings.serviceZone = QBConnectionZoneTypeDevelopment;
QBSettings.networkIndicatorManagerEnabled = YES;
[QBSettings enableXMPPLogging];
```

But I was being overzealous. If I comment out some lines, I get better results:

```
//  [QBSettings setAutoReconnectEnabled:YES];
//  [QBSettings setChatDNSLookupCacheEnabled:YES];
//  // for development
//  QBSettings.serviceZone = QBConnectionZoneTypeDevelopment;
//  QBSettings.networkIndicatorManagerEnabled = YES;
//  [QBSettings enableXMPPLogging];
```

So the issue seems to be with the commented-out lines.